# Remove yellow border on dojo buttons in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, dojo

how do I remove the yellow border on buttons that appear in Google Chrome.
I have tried to override the style, but imagine if you have to do this for every button.

[image]

```
.dijitReset .dijitStretch .dijitButtonContents{
    outline:none;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually that worked for me. I did this (since I use claro theme)

```
.claro *
{
    outline: none;
}
```

So when you do something like this `<body class="claro"> ... </body>` it should work. 
I've been looking for a way to do this since a few days but your css snippet took me into the right direction.